# Does font-size differ in quality?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-size

I notised a difference in quality when fading in and out some text. When font-size is 48px it doesn't transform as much as when it is 50px. And i figured I must ask:

Are there any standard font-sizes that will look better than others when using @font-face? Will some font-sizes have better quality than others? If so, what sizes are they?

By the way, I am using @font-face generated by fontsquirrel.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the quality and legibility of the font.

All fonts are vectors so they should scale perfectly but some aren't made a well as others and can look worse off when scaled.